# Command to extract header of multiple files present in a directory

Tags: shell-script, awk, sed, command-line

For example : there are 50 files present in a Unix directory ,I want to extract header of all the files and write it to a CSV file . CSV file will contain 2 columns 1st column  - file name and 2nd column as header

Comment: Hi, your question is unclear. Also, Excel is out of bounds for Unix&Linux SE. You risk stirring strong emotions when you mention Microsoft here! :)

Comment: You might want to change `copy it in a Excel` to `write it to a CSV` and add concise, testable sample input and expected output plus what you've tried so far to your question. Once you've done that so we know exactly what you're asking about, then we can definitely help you.

Comment: Don't just **describe** your input/output, **show us** some concise, testable sample input/output. Also add what you've tried so far. See [ask].

Comment: I miss what do you understand on "header". Maybe the first line of text files? It would be also useful if you would communicate in round sentences.

Answer (score 3):

Using `head` and *GNU* `sed`:

```
head -n 1 -v * | 
sed 'N;s/.* \(.*\) .*\n\(.*\)/\1,\2/p;D'
```

---

Note: the `-v` is only needed if there's only one file.

Comment: Code explanation pending...

Comment: Not all versions of `head` support `-v`.

Comment: Why is -v needed?

Comment: @seshoumara Did you try it without? :-)

Comment: Yes, head -v -n 1 * gives for me the same as head -n 1 *, hence my confusion.

Comment: (1) Actually, as with ``grep -H``, `-v` *is* needed if there’s only one file in the directory. (Yes, I know that *this* OP claims to have 50 files, but we’re building a knowledgebase of information that should be useful for everybody.)  (2) & (3) See [points #2 and 3 of my comment to nohillside](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/594008/80216#comment1108472_594014).

Answer (score 2):

You can't create XLS files easily from bash, you can create CSV files though and import them into Excel.

```
cd DIRECTORY
rm list-of-headers.csv 2>/dev/null
for f in *; do
    head=$(sed -n -e '1s/"/""/g' -e '1p;q' < "$f")
    file=$(sed 's/"/""/g' <<< "$f")
    printf '"%s","%s"\n' "$file" "$head" >> list-of-headers.csv
done > list-of-headers.csv
```

This will create a new file called `list-of-headers.csv` in the directory consisting of two comma-separated columns with filename and header line.

- `sed -n -e '1s/"/""/g' -e '1p;q'` duplicates any `"` (to adhere to [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180)) in the first line, prints it and then quits (so `sed` doesn't need to read all the other lines in the file)
- `printf ...` will append the line to the target CSV

Comment: (1) Note that by explicitly creating `list-of-headers.csv` (in the current directory) as a separate step before the loop, you cause it (`list-of-headers.csv`) to get swept up in the `*`.  So `list-of-headers.csv` will end up getting an entry that looks like `"list-of-headers.csv","""file1"",""Name Address DOB"""`.  The more traditional approach is to put `> list-of-headers.csv` to the right of the `done`.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) The `head -1` command (option), strictly speaking, appears [not to be supported by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html) (although, being the historic syntax, it is probably still accepted everywhere).  The POSIX-compliant version is  `head -n 1`. (3) You should do  `head -n 1 -- "$f"` to handle files whose names begin with **`-`**.  Or, better yet,  `head -n 1 < "$f"` to handle a file whose name *is* **`-`**.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' LOL. The original version just `rm -f`'ed the file which lead to a comment by another user about using the nuke option unneccessarily. But I agree that creating it before the loop is a bad idea. OTOH so is using `done > list-of-headers.csv` if you run the script in the same directory several times.

Comment: And, looking at the `head ...` part again, using `head` isn't required anyway, `sed` can handle this directly.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this might be what you want:

```
awk -v OFS=, 'FNR==1{print FILENAME, $0}' *
```

or if your CSV requires it's fields to be quoted (e.g. if your file names or header lines can contain commas):

```
awk 'FNR==1{printf "\"%s\",\"%s\"\n", FILENAME, $0}' *
```

YMMV if your file name or first line contain double quotes or newlines (in the case of the file name). You could do this or similar to escape any double quotes:

```
awk 'FNR==1 {
    gsub(/"/,"\"\"",FILENAME)
    gsub(/"/,"\"\"")
    printf "\"%s\",\"%s\"\n", FILENAME, $0
}' *
```

and if your file names can contain newlines and you're generating the CSV to be imported into Excel then you just need to change the ORS so Excel can separate `\n` within a field from `\r\n` at the end of a record:

```
awk -v ORS='\r\n' 'FNR==1 {
    gsub(/"/,"\"\"",FILENAME)
    gsub(/"/,"\"\"")
    printf "\"%s\",\"%s\"\n", FILENAME, $0
}' *
```

If you have GNU awk add `; nextfile` after `$0` for efficiency.